# C# Mongo db driver updating an existing document

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I have an existing document in mongo db with certain properties. When i am trying to update this document with a document with the same id but having more properties it is not updating it. I am using mongo db driver version 2.4.4

Following is the existing document in my db

```
{
    "_id" : "1234",
    "AccountNumber" : "3453535345354",
    "Name" : "new1",
    "PhoneNumber" : "34534535353534543",
    "ETag" : "6ba32e6e-3808-41f5-9b28-0ea882d9c629",
    "Id" : "1234" 
}
```

Now when i am trying to update/ replace this document with the following document it does not work:

```
{
    "AccountNumber": "3453535345354",
    "Name":"new1",
    "PhoneNumber":"34534535353534543",
    "TempProperty":"something new",
    "ETag" : "6ba32e6e-3808-41f5-9b28-0ea882d9c629",
    "Id" : "1234",
    "_id" : "1234"
}
```

Following is the C# code for my upsert method:

```
 public async Task UpsertDocument(string collectionId, string documentId, BsonDocument item)
        {
            var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionId);

            var initialCorrelationId = item["ETag"].AsString;
            item["ETag"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var builders = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;

            var filter = builders.Eq(x => x["Id"], documentId) & builders.Eq(x => x["ETag"], initialCorrelationId);

            var options = new FindOneAndReplaceOptions<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>
            {
                ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.Before,
                IsUpsert = true
            };

            try
            {
                item["Id"] = documentId;
                item["_id"] = documentId;

                await collection.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(filter, item, options);
            }
            catch (MongoCommandException ex) when (ex.Code == 11000)
            {
                throw new ConcurrencyException(
                    $"Error upserting item with id {documentId} and etag {item["Etag"]}{Environment.NewLine}{item.ToJson()}");
            }
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason to have both `Id` and `_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a class as follows:

```
public class Thing
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string ETag { get; set; }
    public string SecondId { get; set; }
}
```

The following code does what you want:

```
var context = new Context();
var tempProperty = "newValue";
var id = "1234"; // This should be unique
var builder = Builders<Thing>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq(x => x.SecondId, id);
var update = Builders<Thing>.Update
    .Set("TempProperty", tempProperty);
context.ThingCollection.UpdateOne(filter, update, new UpdateOptions() {IsUpsert = true});
```

I just renamed Id to SecondId.